# How would I change my approach to useing the address of a temporary object?

Tags: c++11

In creating the mouse events to click in a rectangle, how would I reformat the if statement so that I no longer get an error for taking the address of a temporary object of type 'SDL_Rect'.

```
//Get the mouse offsets
x = event.motion.x;
y = event.motion.y;
SDL_Point point ={x, y};
bool isPointInTileMap = false;

for (int i = 0; i < TILE_HEIGHT; i++ )
{
    for (int j = 0; j < TILE_WIDTH; j++) 
    {
        if (SDL_PointInRect(&point, &(tileMap_[i][j].getBoundRect())))
        {
            isPointInTileMap = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a local:

```
for( int y = 0; y < TILE_HEIGHT; y++ )
{
    for( int x = 0; x < TILE_WIDTH; x++ ) 
    {
        SDL_Rect rect = tileMap_[y][x].getBoundRect();
        if( SDL_PointInRect( &point, &rect ) )
        {
            isPointInTileMap = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This can be simplified further:

```
for( int y = 0; y < TILE_HEIGHT; y++ )
for( int x = 0; x < TILE_WIDTH; x++ ) 
{
    SDL_Rect rect = tileMap_[y][x].getBoundRect();
    if( isPointInTileMap = SDL_PointInRect( &point, &rect ) ) break;
}
```

Don't worry about allocation as `SDL_Rect` is a "POCO" (Plain Ol' C Object) struct, so it lives on the stack and is reclaimed automatically - just make sure you never use use the value of `&rect` outside its scope as it will be dangling pointer.